# How add styled paragraphs in Google Document by API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

i have a functional PHP script to add plain text into Google Document, but I'm struggling to insert paragraphs with styles. What I want to achieve is

1. append heading paragraph with text
2. append paragraph with hyperlink

There is `insertText` request but it's not possible to style this text directly in request. And there is not insertParagraph, so everytime when i insert text i cant even make a new line. https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request

It's frustrating how difficult is to work with Google Docs API, it should be much easier to do such basic tasks, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the texts with the paragraph style and the text style.
- You want to achieve this using Google Docs API.

In this case, how about the following sample request body?

#### Flow:

In order to achieve your goal, when the batchUpdate method is used, as a sample flow, the following flow is used.

1. Insert Texts.

   - In this sample, the texts of `Sample1\n` and `Sample2\n` are inserted.
2. Set paragraph style.

   - In this case, "HEADING_1" and "NORMAL_TEXT" are reflected in the text of `Sample1\n` and `Sample2\n`, respectively.
3. Set text style.

   - In this case, a hyperlink of `https://www.google.com` is set to the text of `Sample2\n`.

When this flow is reflected in a request body, it becomes as follows. Of course, for example, you can change this flow like "1. Insert `Sample1\n`. 2. Set paragraph style. 3. Insert `Sample2\n`. 4. Set paragraph style. 5. Set text style.".

#### Sample request body:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "Sample1\n",
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "text": "sample2\n",
        "location": {
          "index": 9
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updateParagraphStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 8
        },
        "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1"
        },
        "fields": "namedStyleType"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateParagraphStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 9,
          "endIndex": 17
        },
        "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT"
        },
        "fields": "namedStyleType"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 9,
          "endIndex": 16
        },
        "textStyle": {
          "link": {
            "url": "https://www.google.com"
          }
        },
        "fields": "link"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Testing:

When you test this request body with "Try this API" of batchUpdate method of Docs API, you can do it at [this link](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22sampleDocumentId%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22insertText%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22Sample1%5Cn%22%2C%22location%22%3A%7B%22index%22%3A1%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22insertText%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22sample2%5Cn%22%2C%22location%22%3A%7B%22index%22%3A9%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22updateParagraphStyle%22%3A%7B%22range%22%3A%7B%22startIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endIndex%22%3A8%7D%2C%22paragraphStyle%22%3A%7B%22namedStyleType%22%3A%22HEADING_1%22%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22namedStyleType%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22updateParagraphStyle%22%3A%7B%22range%22%3A%7B%22startIndex%22%3A9%2C%22endIndex%22%3A17%7D%2C%22paragraphStyle%22%3A%7B%22namedStyleType%22%3A%22NORMAL_TEXT%22%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22namedStyleType%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22updateTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22range%22%3A%7B%22startIndex%22%3A9%2C%22endIndex%22%3A16%7D%2C%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22link%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%7D%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22link%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D). In this link, the request body has already been set. Please prepare a sample Google Document and set your Google Document ID.

#### Result:

When this request body is used for a Google Document, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)
- [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest)
- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)

Comment: Thank you, now i know where problem was that i couldn't make a new paragraph, it was because i used single quotes `'Sample1\n'` instead of double quotes `"Sample1\n"` now everything else is more clear to me and easier to do by Google API. 

And i copy here another interesting links for future me
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure
|
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#structuralelement
|
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request
|
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents

Comment: @PayteR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: There is an important field, you need use `"fields": "link"` to apply link text style, or the text style won't apply, the doc doesn't mention this and nor describe what `fields` really do.